# How to request permission with chrome.notifications in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to use `chrome.notifications` in my extension. When I load-unpacked my extension, I noticed that just by going to the extension page, I was already granted permission to use notifications.

Shouldn't there be a prompt asking for the user's permission to use notifications? My plan is to give users the option to allow or disallow notifications for the extension. This issue affects my plan to include a button that will ask users for permission for notifications.

`manifest.json`

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "",
  "version": "",
  "description": "",
  "icons": {
    "16": "",
    "48": "",
    "128": ""
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "",
    "default_icon": "",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "html/index.html"
  },
  "incognito": "not_allowed",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    "contextMenus",
    "notifications",
    "storage"
  ],
  "short_name": ""
}
```

I am checking the user permissions for notfications by doing this

```js
 console.log("Request notifications");
    chrome.notifications.getPermissionLevel(function (result) {
      console.log(result); // this returns granted
    });
```

Comment: Unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve). See also [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm, I discovered the documentation for `permissions` and I was able to optionally allow users to enable `notifications` through this code snippet.

```js
  getNotificationPermission() {
      chrome.permissions.request(
        {
          permissions: ["notifications"],
        },
        function (granted) {
          if (granted) {
              // do this
          } else {
             // do that
          }
        }
      );
    },
```

In addition to this, I had to add the `optional_permissions` key in my manifest.json.

`manifest.json`

```json
  "optional_permissions":["notifications"],
```